# Problem having the right input for model.predict() in Keras model

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, mlp, dqn

I have a DQN agent, that receives a state composed of a numerical value indicating its position and a 2D array denoting the requests from a number of users.

My attempt of architecting the neural network was as described [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/24593/keras-dqn-model-with-multiple-inputs-and-multiple-outputs?noredirect=1#comment38863_24593).

Model Summary
[image: Model Summary]

The issue now is in the model.predict() method, it is written like this:

```
target_f = self.model.predict(state)
```

in the method:

```
def replay(self, batch_size): # method that trains NN with experiences sampled from memory
        minibatch = sample(self.memory, batch_size) 
        for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch: 
            target = reward 
            if not done: 
                target = (reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0]))
            target_f = self.model.predict(state) 
            target_f[0][action] = target
            self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0) 
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
```

Where the state can be (agentPosition, [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], ...])

The shape of the state is (2, (11, 3)) if I have 11 users for example (which equals the number of rows in the 2D array of requests).

The error says:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.int32'>", '(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'numpy.ndarray\'>"})'}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

If instead I write it like this:

```
target_f = target_f = self.model.predict(np.array([state[0], state[1]]))
```

The error is then different:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), for inputs ['dense_63_input', 'input_20'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[54],
       [((1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1))]],
      dtype=object)]...
```

Edit:
I did as indicated in the accepted solution, and I get this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-e99a46675915> in <module>
     28 
     29     if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
---> 30         agent.replay(batch_size) # train the agent by replaying the experiences of the episode
     31 
     32     if e % 100 == 0:

<ipython-input-23-91f0ef2e2650> in replay(self, batch_size)
    129                                             np.array(next_state[1]) ])[0])) # (maximum target Q based on future action a')
    130             target_f = self.model.predict( [ np.array(state[0]), \
--> 131                                             np.array(state[1]) ] ) # approximately map current state to future discounted reward
    132             target_f[0][action] = target
    133             self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1011         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
   1012         workers=workers,
-> 1013         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
   1014 
   1015   def reset_metrics(self):

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in predict(self, model, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    496         model, ModeKeys.PREDICT, x=x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose,
    497         steps=steps, callbacks=callbacks, max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
--> 498         workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    499 
    500 

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in _model_iteration(self, model, mode, x, y, batch_size, verbose, sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    408     strategy = _get_distribution_strategy(model)
    409     batch_size, steps = dist_utils.process_batch_and_step_size(
--> 410         strategy, x, batch_size, steps, mode)
    411     dist_utils.validate_callbacks(input_callbacks=callbacks,
    412                                   optimizer=model.optimizer)

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\distribute\distributed_training_utils.py in process_batch_and_step_size(strategy, inputs, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, mode, validation_split)
    460   first_x_value = nest.flatten(inputs)[0]
    461   if isinstance(first_x_value, np.ndarray):
--> 462     num_samples = first_x_value.shape[0]
    463     if validation_split and 0. < validation_split < 1.:
    464       num_samples = int(num_samples * (1 - validation_split))

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The `state[1]` is a tuple like this ((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), ...)

The shape of `np.array(state[0])` is ().
The shape of `np.array(state[1])` is (11, 3).

If I write:

```
self.model.predict( [ np.array(state[0]).reshape(-1,1), np.array(state[1]) ] )
```

It gives an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-e99a46675915> in <module>
     28 
     29     if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
---> 30         agent.replay(batch_size) # train the agent by replaying the experiences of the episode
     31 
     32     if e % 100 == 0:

<ipython-input-26-5df3ba3feb8f> in replay(self, batch_size)
    129                                             np.array(next_state[1]) ])[0])) # (maximum target Q based on future action a')
    130             target_f = self.model.predict( [ np.array(state[0]).reshape(-1, 1), \
--> 131                                             np.array(state[1]) ] ) # approximately map current state to future discounted reward
    132             target_f[0][action] = target
    133             self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1011         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
   1012         workers=workers,
-> 1013         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
   1014 
   1015   def reset_metrics(self):

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in predict(self, model, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    496         model, ModeKeys.PREDICT, x=x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose,
    497         steps=steps, callbacks=callbacks, max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
--> 498         workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    499 
    500 

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in _model_iteration(self, model, mode, x, y, batch_size, verbose, sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    424           max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    425           workers=workers,
--> 426           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    427       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(adapter)
    428       use_sample = total_samples is not None

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in _process_inputs(model, mode, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, shuffle, steps, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    644     standardize_function = None
    645     x, y, sample_weights = standardize(
--> 646         x, y, sample_weight=sample_weights)
    647   elif adapter_cls is data_adapter.ListsOfScalarsDataAdapter:
    648     standardize_function = standardize

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
   2381         is_dataset=is_dataset,
   2382         class_weight=class_weight,
-> 2383         batch_size=batch_size)
   2384 
   2385   def _standardize_tensors(self, x, y, sample_weight, run_eagerly, dict_inputs,

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_tensors(self, x, y, sample_weight, run_eagerly, dict_inputs, is_dataset, class_weight, batch_size)
   2408           feed_input_shapes,
   2409           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
-> 2410           exception_prefix='input')
   2411 
   2412     # Get typespecs for the input data and sanitize it if necessary.

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    571                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    572                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 573                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    574         if not check_batch_axis:
    575           data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_42_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write like this

```py
target_f = self.model.predict( [ np.array(state[0]), np.array(state[1]) ] )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ^^ But do you mean self.model.predict(np.array(state[0]), np.array(state[1])) or self.model.predict(np.array([state[0], np.array(state[1])])) ?

Comment: yes, there was minor mistake, here i corrected it. 
`target_f = self.model.predict( [ np.array(state[0]), np.array(state[1]) ] )`

Comment: The np.array(state[1]) gives an "Out of Range" error, even though when I print it, it doesn't give an error and a value is printed, so it shouldn't be out of range.

Comment: try printing the shape of both state[0] and state[1]

print( np.arrat(state[0]).shape )
print( np.arrat(state[1]).shape )

also can you show full error?

Comment: try putting state[0] in a list, make its shape (n,1)

self.model.predict( [ np.array(state[0]).reshape(-1,1), np.array(state[1]) ] )

Comment: keras dont take single values as input, keras always need input as batch and features, which mean minimum 2D array, you have 2 input so make each 2D array

Comment: I'm new to Deep Learning so it's all a bit confusing. I updated my question.

Comment: your first dense layer need 3D input, try to print the shape of state when training. also can you show your model architecture?

Comment: your state[0] is wrong here, try to compare both during training and here.

Comment: you should look at the code which generate your state and next_state

Comment: There is a brief description of the model architecture here https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/24593/keras-dqn-model-with-multiple-inputs-and-multiple-outputs?noredirect=1#comment38863_24593

Comment: you have 2 input layers,
- 1st input need None,3,11,1
- 2nd need None,32,64

both your state[0] and state[1] dont match the dimensions. recheck how you got these

Comment: Okay, I'll try. Thank you ^^